# csh shell: Numerical operations with variable from file

Tags: file, numbers, compare, csh, cat

I am currently writing a **csh shell skript** and want to compare numbers that are stored in a **file**. There is only one number stored in this file e.g. **-3.675000e+05** or **0.000000e+00**
The problem is, that I get an error:

```
 if: Expression Syntax.
```

when i do:

```
 #!/bin/csh
 set var1 = `cat file1`
 set var2 = `cat file2`
 set var3 = `cat file3`

 set maxtmp = 0

 foreach kmax (va1 var2 var3)
   if ($kmax > $maxtmp) then
     set maxtmp = $kmax
   endif

 end
```

How can I compare those numbers?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two problems with your approach.

First, the scientific notation in your data files is causing some difficulty.  That, however, we can correct using the `printf` command.  If you modify the initial assignment of values to the following

```
set var1 = `cat file1 | xargs printf "%f"`
set var2 = `cat file2 | xargs printf "%f"`
set var3 = `cat file3 | xargs printf "%f"`
```

(or alternatively,

```
set var1 = `cat file` ; set var1 = `printf "%f' $var1`
```

if you want to avoid using the `xargs` command)

this will convert your scientific notation numbers (e.g., -3.675000e+05) into a simple floating point value (e.g., -36750.0000 in your first example).  Csh doesn't under the "e+" in the numbers, and gets confused.

However, we're not out of the woods quite yet.  Csh also doesn't understand negative values, so we need another command to sort those out; `bc` evaluates boolean queries as you need.

Rewriting your `foreach` loop as follows will evaluate the comparisons correctly

```
foreach kmax ( $var1 $var2 $var3 )
    if ( `echo "$kmax > $maxtmp" | bc` ) then
        set maxtmp = $kmax
    endif
end
```

Putting it all together, the following version of your script seems to work:

```
#! /bin/csh

set var1 = `cat file1 | xargs printf "%f"`
set var2 = `cat file2 | xargs printf "%f"`
set var3 = `cat file3 | xargs printf "%f"`

set maxtmp = 0

foreach kmax ($var1 $var2 $var3)
   if (`echo "$kmax > $maxtmp" | bc`) then
       set maxtmp = $kmax
   endif
end

echo $maxtmp
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. In the end I wrote a C Skript for this purpose. Yet, I tried out your approach and it works fine! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Use $ so the **value** of the variables goes in the foreach loop.

Also the first variable should be `var1`.

```
 foreach kmax ($var1 $var2 $var3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You are right, I totally forgot the "$"s. Nevertheless I get an: "if: Badly formed number." Error!

Comment: I've added another solution to handle non-numeric values. Hope it is of some help.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with the issue of non-numeric values-:

```
set maxtmp=0
foreach kmax ($var1 $var2 $var3)
   if ("$kmax" =~ *[^0-9]*)  then
      set kv=-99999
   else
      set kv=$kmax
   endif

   if ( $kv > $maxtmp) then
      set maxtmp = $kv
   endif
end

echo "max is $maxtmp"
```